# Display local image in a WebBrowser control in a WP7 application

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am working on a WP7 application, and I use a WebBrowser control to display html.

The HTML I use is not loaded from the internet, it is written inside the application, so the application can be use offline.

But I don't know how to display an image without downloading it from the internet. The image is in the isolated storage, I can display it in an Image control, but not in the WebBrowser control.

Any way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save the HTML to isolated storage and then use `Navigate(new Uri("folder/index.htm", UriKind.Relative))` you can reference your images/css using relative paths.

Comment: It doesn't work : I can navigate to my html page, but the image is not displayed (except for gif image). Looks like I have the same problem than this guy : http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/76760/466358.aspx

Comment: I guarantee this works, I've done it before for a prototype... unless it's broken in Mango. I'll whip up a sample tomorrow and post it if it works.

Comment: I will work with a gif image if I can't get jpg and png to work. Thanks :)